# Add a custom icon to OS X folder

Tags: macos

[This solution](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10847) from Apple replaces the generic, blue folder with the specified graphic element.

Is there a way to add a custom graphic 'over lay' to the generic, blue folder?  Dropbox is an example of this.

** edit **

I want to do this for one folder.  An alias to the folder should retain the icon as well.

I would prefer to do this without the help of a 3rd-party application.

Comment: So that it becomes a default or just for a given folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way of doing it is just making it yourself. And there is a quite *simple* way of doing it.

1. Select a folder which has the Generic icon.
2. Do **Edit / Get Info** or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.
3. Select the folder's icon, at the top of the *Info Window*, and copy it.
   [image]
4. Open **Preview.app**
5. Do **File / New from Clipboard** or just <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. All of the actual icon's image sizes will appear. Select the first one as it's the biggest one. [image]
6. Copy, from elsewhere, the image you want to use as *overlay* and paste it in the Preview document. For pasting it you'll have to click on the actual image, instead of Preview's selecting panel. [image]
7. Now, either after clicking in the preview's panel or the actual image, do **Edition / Copy**.
8. Select the folder you want to change and do the *Get info* thing as you did before.
9. Select the folder's image at the top of the info window and paste the new *icon* by doing **Edition / Paste**.

This is the final result: [image: The result]

It's quite *nasty*, from a designer's point of view, but it will definitely do the trick.

Comment: This assumes that there is a folder with the desired 'overlay' image.  If there isn't, this won't help.

Comment: @craig No, you can use any image you want as *overlay image* Just copy and paste it on the preview's document.

Comment: #5 produces 10 folder-shaped images of various sizes in Preview.  I don't understand what #6 means--I'm not able to paste another image.

Comment: Those are all of the icon's different sizes. Just choose the first one. Copy an image from elsewhere, the one you're going to use as *overlay*. Then click on the folder's actual image, instead of the panel on the right, and paste it. Let me edit the post with some clarifying pictures!

Comment: Awesome!  Love the icon choice, too.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [**Folders Factory**](http://nice-apps.net/foldersfactory/):

[image: Folders Factory Stamp]

<sup>Contacts might not be the best image for this, but you get the point.

You can also just overlay an image, or stamp a texture or text, but based on the Dropbox I guess this is what you're going for.</sup>

Comment: Is there a way to do this without this application?

Comment: @craig Sure, you can just place a picture on top of the image and edit it yourself using Photoshop/Pixelmator/etc to recreate the stamp effect, but this is the simplest way.